# Replacing specific <a> tags?

Tags: ruby, xml, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm reading some content from an XML file which has the following links in it:

```
<wcm:root xmlns:wcm="http://www.stellent.com/wcm-data/ns/8.0.0" version="8.0.0.0">
 <wcm:element name="NotesToEditors">
  <a href="ssNODE/something">Something</a>
  <a href="ssNODE/hello">hello</a>
  <a href="https//:www.linkkkk.com">linkkkk</a>
 </wcm:element>
```

Reading the file:

```
page_notes_to_editors = doc.xpath("/wcm:root/wcm:element[@name='NotesToEditors']").inner_text
```

Performing clean up:

```
notes = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(page_notes_to_editors)
notes.css('a[href="ssNODE]')
.each{|a| a.replace("<p>#{a.content}</p>")}
```

I tried escaping the double quote like this:

```
notes.css(a["href=\"ssNODE]")
```

It still complains.

But this does not work when the string has weird characters in. This is the error I get:

```
`on_error': unexpected '"' after 'equal'
```

My **desired** result is to convert `ssNODE` links to paragraphs keeping its text.

Any one has any suggestions on how to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code `notes.css('a[href="ssNODE]')` you missed the `"`. Write it as `notes.css('a[href^="ssNODE"]')`

Documented here [`CSS [attribute^=value] Selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)

> The `[attribute^=value]` selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

Comment: I've tried that but it does not pick it up as it looks only for that string alone

Comment: Still doesn't pick it up!! Is there away of telling it to look for something like this notes.css('a[href~="ssNODE/[a-z]"]')

Comment: Very elegant and works just how I wanted it. Thank you very much for your help